# need help trying to get php laravel implementation for redis when using azure redis for cache and clustering

Tags: laravel, redis, azure-redis-cache, predis, phpredis

I have recently started with laravel and php and implemented redis using predis for a single node redis server ( using azure redis for cache ).

All was good until we decided to upgrade and turn clustering size to 2 and then started getting moved errors

I implemented configuration for clustering but azure only gives a single url that is made up of host name port password and ssl option.

I dont know how to use this as both phpredis and predis expect there to be a array of nodes.
but i dont have that.

the errors i have gotten are
moved exceptions
Can't communicate with any node in the cluster
Couldn't map cluster keyspace using any provided seed (phpredis)

i need help i have tried alot of different database.php configs plus client implementation.

added info using ssl port 6380

```
'redis' => [

        'cluster' => true,
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
            'replication' => true,
            'parameters' => [
                // Parameters provide defaults for the Connection Factory
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null), // Redirects need PW for the other nodes
                'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),  // Redirects also must match scheme
            ],
            'persistent' => true,
            'ssl'    => ['verify_peer' => false], // Since we dont have TLS cert to verify
        ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            'persistent' => true,
        ],

        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'persistent' => true,
                    'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 0),
                    'read_write_timeout' => 30,
                ],
            ],

            'options' =>[
                'cluster' =>'redis',
                'replication' => true,
                'persistent' => true,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'context' => [
                'stream' => [
                    'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                    'verify_peer_name' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER_NAME', false),
                    'stream' => [
                        'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            'scheme' => 'tls',
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
          //  'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls'),
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                'verify_peer_name' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER_NAME', false),
            ],
        ],
   ],
```

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'phpredis',
        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ]

    ],
```

```
'redis' => [
        'cluster' => true,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'schema' => 'tls',
        ],

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
            'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
        ],
    ],*/
    'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'), // Use 'phpredis' for the phpredis extension
        'cluster' => [
            'mode' => 'redis', // Set the mode to 'redis' for cluster support
            'seeds' => [
                env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), // List all nodes in your cluster
                // Add other nodes here if you have more
            ],
        ],
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

above is the database.php redis configs i tried .

i need to connect to a cluster of 2 shards in azure redis cache with out error